# having trouble setting up ganglia on three machines

Tags: ubuntu, ganglia

I am running ubuntu 11.10

I have one machine with gmetad, gmond and ganglia-webinterface. When I browse the web interface this machine picks up the local gmond output.

I then added another machine, running only gmond. I didn't really change anything in the config, only the name of the cluster. This machine's output showed up in the web view.

The I tried to add a third machine, similarly to the second, but it's not showing up in the web view. I tried looking at syslog and running as a daemon, but I'm not seeing anything suspicious there.

Any tips for trouble shooting this?

Comment: I guess the third machine's subnet is different from the first two machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using unicast mode, add the following lines to your gmond.conf:

```
udp_send_channel { 
  host = ip.of.your.central.host
  port = 8649 
}
```